# Time on server with Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, time, timezone

So ... I inserted an entry into a table with time stamps. The entry got inserted perfectly. 
But the time stamp that got inserted was :

```
'2015-06-22 10:32:47'
```

I checked the time on the server:

```
Tue Jun 23 01:35:41 IST 2015
```

And inside mysql :

```
select now();
2015-06-23 01:33:57
```

So I check the time in irb.

```
time = Time.now
=> 2015-06-23 01:36:41 +0530
time.zone
=> "IST"
```

The time zone is right .. but I dont know where is it picking up the time from? I cant figure out where is it picking up 10:32 from ? and how do I fix it ?

Appreciate all your help.

Comment: Try fetching both from a Rails console and see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Rails by design converts a datetime into UTC before inserting the value into the database.

This is because, in general, it's not possible to easily represent timezones in the database. Moreover, this approach guarantees the date will be consistent and/or easy to query in the following cases:

- if the server time zone changes or you change server with a different timezone
- if you want to query the date using a different timezone
- if you want to format the date with different time zones depending on the user or other configs

You can customize the default timezone for the app, so that Rails will properly compute the correct difference to UTC when the value is stored into the database. However, you cannot change this behavior: times will always be converted into UTC before being stored in the database.

Generally speaking, if you properly use the Rails date transformation helpers, this shouldn't cause any issue.

For instance, if you want to query all the records where the time is past, the following query

```
Record.where('some_date < ?', Time.current)
```

will properly convert Time.current from your app timezone into UTC, and query the database accordingly.

Comment: So ... is there no way to insert the server time instead of UTC ?

Comment: No, not at the moment.